# Изменить иконки SearchView для api < 21

Tags: android, search, actionbar

Нужно изменить вид поиска, так как по умолчанию иконки лупа и крестик получаются серыми и еле видными. Аппарат Lenovo S650 Андроид 4.4.2 Api 19.

Крестик получилось изменить так

```
int searchCloseId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_close_btn", null, null);
    ImageView searchClose = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchCloseId);
    searchClose.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_clear_white_36dp);
```

Главную иконку лупы получилось изменить так

```
int searchIconId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_button", null, null);
    ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchIconId);
    searchIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_search_white_36dp);
```

Но это не меняет ту лупу которая появляется слева в режиме `hint`. Такой код не помогает

```
int searchIconMagId = searchView.getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("android:id/search_mag_icon", null, null);
    ImageView searchIconMag = (ImageView) searchView.findViewById(searchIconMagId);
    searchIconMag.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_search_white_36dp);
```

Так советал пользователь `metalurgus`

```
ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
    searchIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_search_white_36dp); //иконка поиска
```

Но говорит пустой `searchIcon`. Вот лог

```
.: FATAL EXCEPTION: main   
          Process: com.example.user.h18_2, PID: 8918
          java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.user.h18_2.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:75)
            at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2582)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:341)
            at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:85)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:258)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1311)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:1591)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7.access$100(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:91)
            at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV7$1.run(AppCompatDelegateImplV7.java:130)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5388)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:655)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

xml меню

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/menu_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
    app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Вопрос актуален до сих пор!

Answer (score 1):

В конец onCreateOptionsMenu, перед

```
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

добавьте следующее

```
View searchplate = (View)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_plate);
    searchplate.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.texfield_searchview_holo_light); //фон строки поиска. Можно поменять цвет подчеркнутого поля ввода, например



ImageView searchCloseIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_close_btn);
    searchCloseIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ic_clear_normal); //иконка закрытия поиска

    ImageView voiceIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_voice_btn);
    voiceIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ic_voice_search);//иконка голосового ввода поиска

    ImageView searchIcon = (ImageView)searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_mag_icon);
    searchIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.abc_ic_search); //иконка поиска
```

Comment: Во время вставки иконки говорит `NullPointerException` Что то с совместимостью, что ли не так.